# SCORM for .net desktop offline app?

Tags: .net, standards, desktop-application, scorm

My company develops elearning content as well as platform to author as well as play the content. The course authoring tool as well as the student client are .net based offline desktop applications.

We are pondering if we could use content from other authoring tools such as Adobe Articulate.

Will this problem be solved if we make our products SCORM compliant? or is there any other standard that is to be followed for offline desktop based apps?

Thanks
Arvind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, SCORM is a standard for web-based applications and web-based learning contents. If you want to support Articulate or other products, you will have to support standards such as SCORM or AICC.

If you have any other questions you can check http://support.scorm.com/home